# Redirect via POST - Nothing happening in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have an endpoint that expects a POST request and produces a file. On the front end I need to redirect the page using a form submittal. However, I need to generate the form dynamically (for a variety of reasons on the front end).

Here is my attempt (bear in mind, I had to edit the code a bunch since it sits across various http related components):

```
sendRedirect(options) {
    options.form = this.createForm(options.body);
    options.form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
    options.form.setAttribute('action', redirectTo);
    options.form.submit();
}

createForm(body) {
    let form = window.document.createElement('form');

    return Object.keys(body).reduce((_form, key) => {
        let i = document.createElement('input');
        i.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        i.setAttribute('name', key);
        i.setAttribute('value', body[key]);
        _form.appendChild(i);
        return _form;
    }, form);
}
```

The above works fine in google chrome. However, in firefox, nothing happens (i.e. no network request is sent after the form.submit() executes). I have stepped through the code in firefox and it seems to be executing just fine (i.e. all the variables are set to what they are supposed to be). The code reaches its end of execution at form.submit() and then... nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Thanks to Quentin for the answer. Here is the code that I added to make it work:

```
options.form.style.visibility = 'hidden';
window.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(options.form);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form needs to be part of the document for Firefox to submit it.

Append it to (for example) `document.body` before calling `submit`.